# spring cloud gateway GlobalFilter doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I just started learning spring cloud gateway. I have created a custom GlobalFilter to check the access-key in the request header.The official Spring Cloud Gateway documentation states that a GlobalFilter does not require any configuration and can be activated simply by adding the @Component annotation. I followed this method, but it did not work.
when i send a request to gateway ,it just redirect it to backend without filtering it .

my springboot version is 3.1.4 and
pom.xml is following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

here is ApiApplication code :

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    private String home="http://localhost:8080";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiApplication.class);


    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> proxy(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy){
        return proxy.uri(home + "/cves").get();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);}
```

here is my custom filter code :

```
@Component
public class ApiKeyFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiKeyFilter.class);
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        String apiKey = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("access-key");
        System.out.println(apiKey);
        log.info("ApiKeyFilter is being called");
        if (!isValid(apiKey)) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }
    
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
    
    private boolean isValid(String apiKey) {
        return "123".equals(apiKey);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -100;
    }
}
```

here is application.yml :

```
spring: cloud: gateway: discovery: locator: enabled: false
```

After starting Spring Boot, I printed out the loaded beans and noticed that ApiKeyFilter had been loaded. However, when I added a breakpoint to its filter method for debugging, I discovered that the program did not enter the filter method at all. In addition, I also tried debugging the default GlobalFilters of Spring Cloud Gateway, such as RemoveCachedBodyFilter, and found that it was not taking effect either.
If there is any other information you need from me, I would be happy to provide it. Thank you very much for your help.